# Get content from domain A on domain B

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, dns, cname

So let's say I have two domains: `www.foo.com` and `www.bar.com`. They are on seperated servers (for now, that could be changed) and we've built a new site for the `bar` content that you can access now by `www.foo.com/bar`

As far, as good, every thing is working. But now we want to display the `bar` content at `www.bar.com`. If we'd just make a `C-Name` we would still have to type `www.bar.com/bar` which is kind of strange.

What can we do to get the content of `www.foo.com/bar` ar `www.bar.com` (of course `www.foo.com/bar/baz/123` should be available at `www.bar.com/baz/123` and so on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to redirect, then you will have to proxy on `www.bar.com` using `[P]` Flag. So on your `www.bar.com` server .htaccess you should be able to do something like this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.foo.com/bar/$1 [P]
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p

Note: mod_proxy is required and needs to be enabled in Apache if not already.

Comment: I was looking for that one (:

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your htaccess

```
 RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)/?$ http://www.bar.com/$1
```

The above example redirects the entire site to domain b.

If you want to redirect /bar requests to domain B , then try the following

```
 RedirectMatch 301 ^/bar/(.*)/?$ http://www.bar.com/$1
```